# Django REST depth = 1 without quit the field form

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Model:

```
class StoreSettings(models.Model):
    slider_images = models.ManyToMany......
```

In Serializer I have this:

```
class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StoreSettings
        fields = ('slider_images', )
        depth = 1
```

Adding `depth = 1` The Multiple choice field is removed of the Django Rest form

I want to add `depth = 1` but, with the form like It didn't happend

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding `depth=1` means you want nested forms which Django REST framework doesn't support. Therefore it discards the field.

Comment: OK, so, how can I do for solve this problem?, exist another form to show a field in the form but not in the json? and upside down?